# android - defining elemnts of any layout on a new screen (activity)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

i want to dispaly text views n other stuff on 1 screen and when ny1 of those is selected i want to go another screen which already has textviews and radiobuttons on it???

how do i do that???

Answer (score 0):

Read more about using `Intents` and `startActivity`.
You pass data from one activity with the other using `Extras`. putString